# Which verb is more correct in "Which shirts is/are she bringing?"

Tags: grammar

Neither sounds quite correct. No, the question is not well-phrased. But which form is correct?, and is there a better phrasing?

Comment: It's "she" that is bringing the shirts -- they aren't bringing themselves.

Comment: So, "Which shirts is she bringing?" That was my inclination as it works with the reordered, "She is bringing which shirts?"

Comment: Or "Which shirts are the ones that she is bringing?"

Comment: I'm not sure why the question got a down vote. Should I have asked it differently somehow?

Comment: Mainly, I suspect that folks feel that questions at this level belong on English Language Learners Stack Exchange, not here.  If you're going to ask such a question here you'd need to describe how you've researched it so far, and what specific questions you have regarding what you've read.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize there was another English forum. When I started, I think there may have only been this one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use "is". "Shirts" is the object and "she" is the subject. The verb - in this case "to be" - has to agree with the subject. Hence you would say:

> Which shirts **is** she bringing?

You can also say:

> Which are the shirts that she is bringing?

Another example of this usage is:

> How many shirts is she bringing?

Comment: You could also try, "Which shirts will she bring?" or

Comment: Poor wording? Sounds totally normal to me.

Answer (score 1):

CORRECT: "Which shirts is she bringing?"

she = subject

is bringing = verb, present continuous, agrees with the subject (pronoun) "she"